# Customizing ActionBar style

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

I really need on customizing ActionBar. How do I change color and the location of it? These are my current code:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        this.ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        InitializeData();

        ActionBar bar = ActionBar;
        bar.AddTab(bar.NewTab().SetText("Test1").SetTabListener(this));
        bar.AddTab(bar.NewTab().SetText("Test2").SetTabListener(this));
        bar.DisplayOptions = ActionBarDisplayOptions.ShowCustom | ActionBarDisplayOptions.UseLogo;
        bar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        bar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    }
```

Main.axml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:background="@color/backgroundcolor">
                <include
        layout="@layout/TitleBarLayout" />
```

TitleBarLayout.axml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/TitleBarLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/headercolor">
    <Button
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_width="142.9dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/HeaderMenuButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.8dp"
        android:background="@color/headercolor" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the image of what I want: [image: change actionbar location]

I just wan't it in this layout format:
- Title (purple)
- Actionbar (white)
- Rest of the page content

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Use this style generator http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/actionbar-style-generator/

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Now I can generate the style but how would I have a title on top of that? I wanted a TitleBar that has a button

Comment: You can put everything on title bar, create your custom view for actionbar.

Comment: You are not exactly making yourself clear what it is you want to achieve. Can you make a drawing of the expected result?

Comment: Are you not looking at the picture? I've stated I want those tabs on the bottom and the TitleBar on top.